# need to scan from the user string and than to divide the sentence to variables , (float and char)

Tags: c

i ran into a problem when i tried to scan sentence from the user and then to split it to different variables. 
the issue is that i need (across the first word) to scan different types of variables. 
for example

when the user print "hey 1 2" (after the word hey will be 2 numbers)
so i can do sscanf_s(str, "%s %f %f %f", command, sizeof(command), &rows1, &colums1);

**but**  when the user print "bye friend 10" (after the word bye will be 1 word and 1 number).

how can i wrote code that know across the first word what types (and how much) to scan ? thank you

Comment: read the input as one string and parse the input

Comment: Look at the first word and then select appropriate code to run.